# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find de sum of this serie using the partial sums?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left[\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)}\right]$$

Thanks!

Comment: The sum of the logarithms is the logarithm of the product.  Telescope

Answer (score 0):

For $k$ fixed:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^k\log\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)}\right)&=&\sum_{n=1}^k2\log(n+1)-\log(n)-\log(n+2)\\
&=&\left(\sum_{n=1}^k\log(n+1)-\log(n)\right)+\left(\sum_{n=1}^k\log(n+1)-\log(n+2)\right)\\
&=&(\log(k+1)-\log(1))-(\log(k+2)-\log(2))\\
&=&\log\left(\frac{2(k+1)}{k+2}\right)\\
&\to&\log2
\end{eqnarray}$